# Access server files with ArcGIS javascript api

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-server

I have a geoprocessing service that takes two parameters: netCDF (file) and Date (str). I'm working off of the demo found [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/gp_resultmapservice.html).

The issue I have is getting the netCDF file to the geoprocessing service. By creating an upload feature I can see how I would be able to provide the needed parameter but I already have all the necessary files server side.

How can I get my web application to read local netCDF data into the geoprocessing service?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My testing application can be found [here](http://sroarcgis.ducks.org/wsitest/).

Service: http://sroarcgis.ducks.org/ducksunlimited/rest/services/wsi_tool/GPServer

I receiver the error message: Error {code: 400, message: "Invalid or missing input parameters.", details: Array[0], log: undefined, httpCode: 400}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with ESRI support they said that I would need to enable uploads on my web server, then upload each file individually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applies to your geoprocess, but I got this same error message and I finally fixed my problem:

Make sure you have the same fields in the search results as you have in the table the search is linked to.

It was a simple fix that took me awhile to find (as these things usually go). I had included a field that was visible in other tables, but that I had had turned off in this table before publishing the map.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your "Invalid or missing input parameters." error, you may be able to resolve this error using the following steps:

1. Log into ArcCatalog
2. Create a database connection as the user who is the owner of the table.
3. Select the table in the Catalog Tree.
4. Click the Preview tab. (Not sure if this step is really needed, but it will confirm that the metadata was refreshed properly.)

This error can crop up if the table columns change in some way. I think this process refreshes the SDE Metadata associated with the table.